# how to display escape sequences in JSON in Java script text box

Tags: javascript, json, jsp, ajax.net

I am sending a JSON object from a servlet to JSP using AJAX. My JSON object contains a String value inside. and that string contains double quotes within that. My JSON does not parse it. I get the following error:

```
 {"diagnosis":[{"NAME":"new_diagnosis_1 \[1020\]:2000000006001"},{"NAME":"new_diagnosis_2 \[1021\]:2000000006003"},{"NAME":"new_"dise"sed \[1023\]:2000000009001"},{"NAME":"new_d"ise"sef \[1024\]:2000000009003"}]}
```

note `new_"dise"sed` and `new_d"ise"sef`

I need a solution.

Answer (score 2):

your json is not valid

try this

```
{
    "diagnosis": [
        {
            "NAME": "new_diagnosis_1 [1020]:2000000006001" 
        },
        {
            "NAME": "new_diagnosis_2 [1021]:2000000006003" 
        },
        {
            "NAME": "new_\"dise\"sed [1023]:2000000009001" 
        },
        {
            "NAME": "new_d\"ise\"sef [1024]:2000000009003" 
        } 
    ]
}
```

use `\` to escape quotes

you can validate your `json`  here 
http://www.jsonlint.com/

Comment: Thanks a lot gowri... I will try now itself

Comment: hai gowri can you please suggest me any good books for learning Jquery I am a beginner...I know Java Script and AJAX

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2711205/what-jquery-book-you-would-recommend-for-a-beginner
jquery tips
http://www.tvidesign.co.uk/blog/improve-your-jquery-25-excellent-tips.aspx